# Jersey 2 LoggingFilter

Tags: spring, rest, configuration, jersey

I have a web application configured to use Jersey along with Spring to provide the back end services and dependency injection.

I'm having trouble determining the best way to add the LoggingFilter, provided by Jersey 2.3, into my application.  If possible I'd like to do so outside of the web.xml file as an init-param, and instead do so in Java configuration files.

I'm aware of the ResourceConfig class, which has the register(Class clazz) method, but am unsure the best way to get a handle on it.

What's the most effective way to register filters outside of web.xml with Jersey 2.3/Spring?

My web.xml is here:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            prototype.config.ApplicationConfig
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>prototype.resources</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Nate K.

Comment: Figured it out - I decided to use a different property on my servlet - javax.ws.rs.Application.  

I map this to a class that extends ResourceConfig, where I can set any configuration available on ResourceConfig, such as packages or registering filters.  
This works - however, is there a way to get a hold configuration after the initial Servlet instantiation?